# Make buttons cut off when over the edge of other DIV

Tags: html, css, z-index, behind

I have a main DIV, and some buttons within that DIV. I want the buttons to be cut off when they go off the edge of the DIV (like this image here, where the blue is the body, the light grey is the div and the dark grey are the buttons.)

How can I do this?

[image]

My HTML:

```
<body style="background-color: blue;">
    <div id="container">
        <button style="position: absolute; left:-50px; width:150px; height:50px;">Button</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below css to your wrapper div

```
#wrapperDiv{overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Keith in the comments, just use `overflow: hidden;`. (See snippet.)

```css
.hide-buttons {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.top-button {

    position: absolute;
    min-width: 30%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 35%;

}

.left-button {
  
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  
}

.right-button {
  
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="hide-buttons">
  
  <input type="button" value="Top Button" class="top-button">
  <input type="button" value="Left Button" class="left-button">
  <input type="button" value="Right Button" class="right-button">
  
</div>  
</div>
```